Is there a path-connected, "anti-convex" subset of $\mathbb R^2$ containing $(\mathbb R\smallsetminus \mathbb Q)^2$?
This question was firstly asked in Mathematics Stack Exchange. Getting no answer, I copied it to Math Overflow, as Moishe Kohan commented.
For a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb R$, I say a subset $S$ of $V$ is "anti-convex" if $\forall a,b\in S (a\ne b)$, $\exists t\in \mathopen]0,1\mathclose[$, $b+t(a-b)\not\in S$. For example, all hollow circles $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$ on $\mathbb R^2$ are anti-convex.
Now I want to know if there is a path-connected, "anti-convex" subset of $\mathbb R^2$ containing $(\mathbb R\smallsetminus \mathbb Q)^2$.
My approach I've proven the case when $(\mathbb R\smallsetminus \mathbb Q)^2$ were replaced by a countable subset of $\mathbb R^2$ - Put them in order, and using hollow circles to connect the adjacent elements will work.
Further question (edited thanks to Sam Hopkins) Actually, I originally guessed that, if $\dim V\ge 2$, then for all anti-convex subset $S$, there's a path-connected anti-convex set containing $S$, but I'm already stuck at this special case.
Edit Since the original question was solved in Math Overflow, the one who answered my further question will receive the bounty.

Do you mean $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \mathbb{Q}^2$? The case of $A = (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})^2$ is trivial as any line between two points in $A$ must contain a point for which at least one of the coordinates is rational.

@Comma You're proving that $A$ itself is anti-convex, but $A$ itself isn't path-connected. Actually, any subset of an anti-convex set is anti-convex, so you can't find a supset of $\mathbb R^2\backslash \mathbb Q^2$ that is anti-convex.

Ah I missed the path connectedness requirement.

Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/471047/is-there-a-path-connected-anti-convex-subset-of-mathbb-r2-containing-m
